# How can I optimize a slow MySQL query that uses multiple LEFT JOINs and a GROUP BY clause?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a MySQL query that performs several LEFT JOINs on large tables, and then uses a GROUP BY clause to aggregate the results. The query takes a long time to execute and I'm looking for ways to optimize it. Here is the current query:

```
SELECT
t1.col1, t2.col2, t3.col3, SUM(t4.col4)
FROM
table1 t1
LEFT JOIN
table2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.table2_id
LEFT JOIN
table3 t3 ON t3.id = t1.table3_id
LEFT JOIN
table4 t4 ON t4.id = t1.table4_id
GROUP BY
t1.id
```

Any suggestions on how to improve the performance of this query would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Adding the EXPLAIN output for your query, the DDL for the tables and the relevant index stats would be a useful starting point.

Comment: Step 1:  Understand the difference between `LEFT JOIN` and `INNER JOIN`.  The formulation you have does not make a lot of sense.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You are misusing MySQL's [notorious nonstandard extension to GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html). Disable that extension with `SET sql_mode = CONCAT_WS(',',@@sql_mode, 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY')`, then try your query again. You'll need more terms in your GROUP BY clause. It is difficult to puzzle out what you want to do from your query in this case.